# Where is the best and easiest place to store global website settings

Tags: asp.net

I'm just putting together an internal data system for a client, which is ASP.NET VB, backed by an SQL database, on an in-house IIS7.5 dedicated server.

I want to store certain global settings, such as the age limit for news articles, admin contacts etc, in a file NOT within the database (i.e. to avoid unnecessary database query's)

Where would the best place to store this be? global.asax? app.config? or a custom XML file? how would i import these at runtime? (probably to session variables)

ETA:
Also - the settings must be editable from within the site, i.e. an admin section i'm yet to build

Comment: @Irish Maybe you mean web.config, but I thhink the last requirement rules that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need these settings to be editable, then the simplest place to store them would be in a database table. You're already building a layer to get in and out with CRUD operations, so adding this little extra won't hamper you. This will also help you keep your web.config clean and your supporting libraries will not need an extra app.config built into them.

Resource files and embedded app.config files are not editable so those preferred methods don't meet your requirements. You don't want people accessing the web.config directly (even through an interface) because changes to the web.config cause the application pool to recycle. A custom XML file would work, but you would have to build a separate parsing engine to get in and out of it. While this is simple, it would be unnecessary since you're already building an access interface for the rest of your database.

If you're really hating yourself though, you could combine the two into a custom xml file stored in the database as an XElement.

Comment: hhaha! "if you're really hating yourself"!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.

I decided the easiest method, given that the details may only need altering a couple of times a year, was to set session variables in global.asax